# What is the point of the terminator enable pin of an RS485?

Tags: resistors, rs232

I am working on programming the logic to test an RS485 controller (reference manual [here](http://cds.linear.com/docs/Datasheet/2881fd.pdf)). On page 8 of the reference manual, pin A2 is described as "Terminator Enable" (TE), which enables a resistors between pins A and pins B.

What is the point of having the option to have a resistor between pins A and pins B?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you don't want terminating resistors on every node of your network. If you did all those resistors would be in parallel and the network's load would be too high.
Place terminating resistors at both ends of the bus only.
Ideally, in transmission lines the terminating resistors should match the line's characteristic impedance. Then a signal arriving at the line's end would be absorbed completely in the resistor, without reflections occurring.

Comment: I once worked with an engineer who made the 'Terminator Enable' for each node software selectable from the controller. He hadn't considered how the control message would get through to the end of the line under severe reflection conditions!

Comment: @Mike - how did his software know the physical location of the nodes?

Comment: The idea was fine in principle. An installation engineer would configure the properties of the controller and each node on a laptop then upload the configuration to the controller, which would configure the nodes. It failed on the first site (he was my manager:)